# SQL time range query

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I am trying to query an SQL table using a time range via the statement below.

SELECT columnName FROM tableName WHERE time between 2013-05-03 22:47:02 and 2013-11-19 22:47:02

Where the column 'time' is of type TIMESTAMP, an example entry is

2013-09-07 15:00:00

I am getting the response that there is a syntax problem can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try quoting the times in the query. `SELECT columnName FROM tableName WHERE time between '2013-05-03 22:47:02' and '2013-11-19 22:47:02'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need single quotes around the datetime values.